# Problems with returning values in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I converted a list to a Counter. The problem occurs when I try to return my values. I tried `counter.values()` but I receive my original list instead of the item counts. Any suggestions?

```py
a=[1,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,66,44,3]
c=Counter(a)
print(c.values())
```

output:
[1,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,66,44,3]

Comment: please post your original code. and your input and expected output.

Comment: calling `values` should return the counts not our original list.

Answer (score 1):

`keys()` returns the items in your original list. `values()` returns the associated counts. `items()` returns key-value (key-count) pairs.

Comment: what im really trying to end up with is that, i give two arguments(a,n) and if the value is less then n i want to delete the pair of the key and value

Comment: `for k, v in c.iteritems(): if v < n: del c[k]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: that'll throw a dictionary-size-changed error.

Comment: @DSM. Indeed.  That will teach me not to post answers from my iPod while watching football.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with OP that c.values() should return the count and not the item itself. I believe that is the expected behavior. Anything else is likely to be a bug. Check the Python bugdb or try a newer version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a=[1,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,66,44,3]
>>> c=Counter(a)
>>>
>>> c.keys() # elements of the original list taken once
dict_keys([1, 66, 3, 4, 5, 44, 2])
>>>
>>> c.values() # occurrences of each element
dict_values([3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2])
>>>
>>> c.items() # list of tuples (element, occurrence)
dict_items([(1, 3), (66, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 1), (44, 1), (2, 2)])
>>>
>>> c[66] # occurrences of element 66
1
```